# Validar un intervalo de minutos

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy trabajando en una página donde pido la hora y minuto que desean
y a su vez pido un intervalo de minutos que desean cortar.

Por decir `04:50` y de esos `50` min deseo cortar solo `5` min
lo que quiero yo. ¿Cómo validar para que cuando el usuario elija un intervalo de `20` minutos, éste no le deje avanzar y marque error porque no puede cortar más minutos de los que le quedan? ¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo hacerlo?

Éste es mi código:

```html
Minutos a cortar
<input type="number" min="00" max="59" oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)" placeholder="00" onkeypress="return isNumeric(event)" id="mine" name="mine[]">

Minutos      
<select data-style="btn-primary" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-size="5" data-width="auto" multiple data-max-options="1"  data-actions-box="true" name="min[]" id="min">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
    <option value="04">04</option>
    <option value="05">05</option>
    <option value="06">06</option>
    <option value="07">07</option>
    <option value="08">08</option>
    <option value="09">09</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option> 
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>   
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>                                                                   
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>   
    <option value="31">31</option>
    <option value="32">32</option>
    <option value="33">33</option>                                                                   
    <option value="34">34</option>
    <option value="35">35</option>
    <option value="36">36</option>
    <option value="37">37</option>
    <option value="38">38</option>
    <option value="39">39</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>   
    <option value="41">41</option>
    <option value="42">42</option>
    <option value="43">43</option>                                                                   
    <option value="44">44</option>
    <option value="45">45</option>
    <option value="46">46</option>
    <option value="47">47</option>
    <option value="48">48</option>
    <option value="49">49</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>   
    <option value="51">51</option>
    <option value="52">52</option>
    <option value="53">53</option>                                                                   
    <option value="54">54</option>
    <option value="55">55</option>
    <option value="56">56</option>
    <option value="57">57</option>
    <option value="58">58</option>
    <option value="59">59</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: El código sólo se refiere a la parte de entrada de datos. No se incluye algo sobre validación ni tampoco lo buscado/investigado sobre el tema.

Answer (score 0):

Podría implementar de forma dinámica con `Jquery` que cada vez que seleccione los minutos no le muestre para seleccionar opciones mayores, para esto se emplearía

- [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) para detectar el cambio en el `input`
- [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) para seleccionar los `options` a eliminar.
- [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) para añadir `options` dependiendo del valor del `input`

```js
$(document).on('change focus', '#mine', function(event) {
  $('#min').find('option').remove();
    var val = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 1; i <= val; i++) {
       $('#min').append($('<option>', {
          value: i,
          text: i
      }));
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Minutos Deseados
  <input type="number" min="00" max="59" o placeholder="00" id="mine" name="mine[]">

Minutos      
  <select data-style="btn-primary" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-size="7" data-width="auto" multiple     id="min">
  
   </select>
```

Comment: es parecida la idea companero, pero que pasa si deseo `10` minutos apartir de la hora `15:20`